# Адрес страницы совпадает с именем директори в файловой системе

Tags: .htaccess

Необходимо сделать url страницы site.com/catalog, но дело в том, что в корне сайта есть директория с именем catalog, поэтому я получаю ошибку 403 при обращении к этому адресу. Как можно в htaccess решить эту задачу? Ниже некоторые из директов в htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes -Includes +FollowSymLinks
```

если это не папка, не файл и не файл конкретного формата

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp|js|css|svg)
```

перенаправляем все запросы на файл index.php, все что в url до вопросительного знака пишем в get-параметр _route_

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

Видимо что-то вроде подобного

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^catalog/?$
```

либо до этих правил написать отдельное

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/?$ index.php?route=catalog [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Опечатка, во втором варианте get-параметр \_route_.
В общем попробовал. первый вариант не сработал, а при втором варианте редирект на site.com/catalog/?_route_=catalog

Comment: Взял ответ за основу решения, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос следующим образом. Сперва отключил автоматическое добавление слешей директориям, чтобы не было редиректов.

```
# лучше не использовать если включен Options +Indexes
DirectorySlash Off
```

И потом дополнил текущее условие

```
# REQUEST_URI начинается со слеша
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/?$
```